# How validate max number of files before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm using the upload file plugin and I need to validate the number of files added before upload the file...Something like this

```
        $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        filestoupload++;
        var numOfDivs = $('.request').size();
        if (numOfDivs < filestoupload) {
            upload = false; // Is just an example.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, on your fileupload definition add a beforesend, and there do the validation

```
 var maxfiles=3;
 $('#fileupload').fileupload(({
    url: postFileUrl,
    submit: function (event, files) {
        //check for max files THIS IS WHERE YOU VALIDATE
        //console.log(files.originalFiles.length);
        var fileCount = files.originalFiles.length;
        if (fileCount > maxFiles) {
            alert("The max number of files is "+maxFiles);
            throw 'This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript';
            return false; 
        }
    }
  });
```

that throw is by far not elegant, if you happend to implement this and find a way to avoid that please make me know (for now is necesary or it will display the error alert for each file uploaded)

Answer (score 1):

use data.files.length

```
 $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    var fileCount = data.files.length;
    if (fileCount < filestoupload) {
        upload = false; 
    }
});
```